# Use a set as the key in Dataset#groupByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to use a `Set` as the key with `Dataset#groupByKey`?  It looks like, for sets, Spark uses an encoder meant for arrays.  This causes the order of values within a set to change the outcome.

Here's an example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Main extends App {

  val spark =
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("spark")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  println {
    List("foo", "bar")
      .toDS()
      .groupByKey {
        case "foo" => Set(1, 2)
        case "bar" => Set(2, 1) // append .toList.sorted.toSet to get expected behavior
      }
      .keys
      .collect
      .mkString("\n")
  }

  spark.close()
}
```

I expect this to produce a single key, `Set(1, 2)`.  Instead, it produces two.  The encoder looks like it's meant for ordered collections:

```scala
val e: Encoder[Set[Int]] = implicitly[Encoder[Set[Int]]]
println(s"${e}") // class[value[0]: array<int>]
```

Is this a bug?  Should there be an encoder for sets?  Is that even feasible?

Comment: Spark internally can not represent a set, only an array. What about converting them into a sorted list?

Comment: That makes sense.  A sorted list would work fine; I was just surprised that a set wouldn't work.  Could the encoder constructor be changed to sort the data when it comes from a set?  I don't know enough about how encoders work.

Comment: It probably could, it may even just support the set datatype internally. I just doubt it will be ever done, as **Spark** really doesn't care about the typed API but just the SQL API for python fanboys who don't really know anything about types nor datastructures so they would probably will never do it.

Comment: A simpler way to demonstrate this: `List(Set(1,2),Set(2,1)).toDS().distinct().collect()` gives two results, rather than one: `Array(Set(1,2), Set(2, 1))`.